# Open browser on click of FCM notification when app is killed

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting a link through FCM Push Notification which I want to open in browser. I've done it in this manner:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

But the problem is, on click of notification it is opening browser only when app is in foreground. But when app is killed or if it is in background it doesn't open browser, it just opens the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app is in the background and FCM Push Notification contains `notification` payload inside request. Then `onMessageReceived` method won't trigger so it won't open any browser.

If you want to open browser when app is not in foreground, you have to use the following syntax while sending notification request (Try it in Postman).

```
{
  "to": "device token",
  "priority" : "normal",
  "data":{
    "title": "title",
    "body": "body"
  }

}
```

Above request should not contain `notification` payload field i.e.,

```
{
  "to": "device token",
  "priority" : "normal",
  "notification":{   },
  "data":{
  "title": "title",
  "body": "body"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Application context in 
`PendingIntent.getActivity`